# trouble with frontpage server extensions when publishing a web service

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, iis

I'm creating a web service for my app to talk to. When I go to publish it (locally), VS tells me that the server doesn't appear to have frontpage server extensions installed. It was correct.

Specifically the message says: "The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed. If FrontPage Server Extensions are installed, this error can occur because the _vti_bin virtual directory is not marked as executable. To correct this problem, run Internet Information Services Manager, select the Web server that has the problem, and then use the Check Server Extensions command."

I installed the extensions via the xp pro cd. I registered them as instructed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298158).

I registered asp using "aspnet_regiis -i -enable".

I open IIS, showing only my machine and only the 'default web site' running. I also can't quite figure out how to run the "Check Server Extensions" command.

I'd like host this web service locally so that I can test it and then send it off to the server admin to install it on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to publish the service? FrontPage Server Extensions are no longer required.

Comment: right click the project > publish. Enter http://localhost:port/ into the dialog and go.

Comment: Is there a bar on the left with choices of the kind of publish location? Do you have "Local IIS" selected? I would suggest you try to publish to an IIS location without a port. Also, in your project properties, is there a "Web" tab with options on where the project should be located? If so, tell it to create the virtual directory for you. Then set it back the way it was. You should then be able to publish to the created Virtual Directory.